# Free gift timer in crossy road

Tags: crossy-road

I just restarted crossy road and the free gift timer jumped from 6 minutes to 6 hours when I closed and reopened the game. Is the free gift timer relative to how many characters you have unlocked?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how many characters you have. Sometimes it goes slow, and sometimes it is fast. It all depends on how much you have played crossy road, and how many characters you have.